# Angular Bootstrap navbar not showing correct style

Tags: css, angular

I am following Udemy course on Angular, and i am facing problems with the `nav bar`
this is the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" >Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

what I am trying to achieve is this   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgeD3.png)
but what i am getting is this
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En2jw.png)

i added the button with class `btn-primary` to check that bootstrap is working

when i inspected i found that collapse has display none, so i removed the collapse class and got this
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Visf0.png)

the i tried copying the header code from the project files i downloaded and for the same wrong result

what could be the problem and what is the solution?
thanks

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots, include them on the post so that references stay intact. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, if this tutorial is old a little bit make sure to install the correct bootstrap version example "npm i bootstrap@v4.4.1"

**Second**, try to follow bootstrap navigation template examples
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/

I guess in your case you forget to define at what screen size the navigation should expand... for example add "navbar-expand-md" to nav class property and the menu will show up

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default">
```